# Create PHP array with the same key name

Tags: java, php, arrays, spring-boot, postman

i have created an api in java that accepts (name="sample" multipart[]) and when i'm requesting from php curl,
curl file objects in the array overwrites the old one to new, it means, only one value in the array is accepted.

This is one of the code that i tried:

```
$files = array(
   'path/sample1.png',
   'path/sample2.png',
);

$postfields = array();

foreach ($files as $index => $file) {
   if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { 
     $file  = new CURLFILE(realpath($file), mime_content_type($file), basename($file));
   } 
   else {
    $file = '@' . realpath($file);
   }
   $postfields["sample"] = $file;
 }
```

Note: I already tried sending a request in postman and it works perfectly with same keyname. The generated code have the same keyname in the post fields like this..
"sample" => "",
"sample" => ""

I don't know what to follow since the postman request is success, i tried also using the generated code from postman but the output is the same as stated above.

CURL:

```
  CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 0,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => true,
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
```

Comment: Make it an array like `$postfields["sample"][] = $file;`

Comment: thanks for the answer, solved the same key name problem but unfortunately i didn't see that part if the keyname was solved because it still has an error, "array to string convertion" in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => ' '. If i make convert it, that would not be accepted in the api since the content type is multipart.

Comment: Also set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);`. That changes behavior of `$postfields` decomposition.

Comment: hmm! i already have that. i'll just edit my post for reference.